# Prior line should be printed if the next line starts with a particular word

Tags: unix

How do I print a line which matches a particular pattern and the line before it?

I do have a dump like this:

```
Apple:Orange=9942501133;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501144;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501155;
Apple:Orange=9942501166;
Apple:Orange=9942501177;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501188;
Apple:Orange=9942501199;
Apple:Orange=9942501200;
Apple:Orange=9942501211;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501222;
```

The output result to be the above line of "Fault Code 9" with Fault Code 9 included:

```
Apple:Orange=9942501133;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501144;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501177;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501211;
Fault Code 9
```

Comment: Merged;  Please check the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  No need to close as dupe now.

Comment: If you are wondering if it was merged, check the edit history (click the link ("edited X ago") above the last person to have edited the question, up there ^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
cat yourfile | perl -e 'while(<STDIN>) { if(/Fault Code 9/) { print $prev; } $prev=$_; }'
```

In pure shell:

```
cat yourfile | while read line
do
  if [ "$line" == "Fault Code 9" ]; then
    echo "$prev"
  fi
  prev=$line
done
```

Comment: Lasseoe ... It works ...Can u guide me to modify the output as 
Apple:Orange=9942501133;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501144;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501177;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501211;
Fault Code 9

ie, Number folled by Fault code .

Comment: @user: read the man pages for the commands used, and make the modifications yourself! We are not being paid to do your work; **you are**.

Answer (score 3):

```
# grep -B1 ^Fault log.txt
```

The `-B` switch means "before".

Comment: Assuming GNU `grep`; POSIX `grep` does not support this option.

Comment: Hi Leffler,
       So kind of u to reply but it does not work.illegal option -- B is the reply from sun server .plz help .
Can u try the below cmd
cat yourfile | perl -e 'while(<STDIN>) { if(/Fault Code 9/) { print $prev; } $prev=$_; }'  and reply

Answer (score 1):

gawk:

```
/^Fault Code 9/ {
  print s
  print $0
}

{
  s = $0
}
```

Comment: This illustrates the basic algorithm - if you need to print N lines prior to the match, then you have to store the N lines.  If you have N > 1, then you also have to worry about making sure that you don't print too much data when the match occurs twice within a space of N lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr -d '\n' <yourfile | grep -E -o '[^; ]+; *Fault Code 9' | sed 's/;.*$//'
```

Comment: @Ether: tr cannot take input from file, cat is necessary

Comment: a cat with one argument is never necessary in the shell, as you can use a funnel: `tr ... < yourfile | grep ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -B1 'Fault Code 9' filename.txt
```

Comment: the output is not as required

Comment: Ether Ji,
what is ment by -B1 . The mentioned command does not work .it throws error like this 
grep: can't open -B1
grep: can't open Fault Code 9

Comment: The `-B` option specifies how many lines *before* the search parameter it will print.  Please type `man grep` at the command line.

Comment: The older question was merged into this one. I'm reopening this one now.